# add row and column to matrix based on sequence and fill it with NaN

Tags: r, matrix, row, fill, col

I have a matrix `mat_1` with specular rows and columns but one of both is missing. So let's say I want rows and columns following the alphabetical order: a, b, c, d, e, but my matrix is missing one of the letter, i.e. b.

How can I generate a code snippet that finds the gap(s) in the alphabetical sequence in `mat_1`, adds the missing row and column, and fills the observations with `NaN` in a second matrix `mat_2`?

Here is my reproducible example:

```
set.seed(100)

#create matrix with missing column and row
mat_1 = matrix(rnorm(16), nrow=4, ncol=4, byrow = TRUE) 

#rename columns and rows
dimnames(mat_1) = list(c("a", "c", "d", "e"), c("a", "c", "d", "e")) 

#expected output
> mat_2
           a    b          c           d           e
a -0.5021924  NaN  0.1315312 -0.07891709  0.88678481
b        NaN  NaN        NaN         NaN         NaN
c  0.1169713  NaN  0.3186301 -0.58179068  0.71453271
d -0.8252594  NaN -0.3598621  0.08988614  0.09627446
e -0.2016340  NaN  0.7398405  0.12337950 -0.02931671
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was an answer a minute ago, which I believe was a very good one, and I actually came by again to comment on it with some modifications, and up-vote it, but it seems it was deleted

In any case here is the updated version of the mentioned answer

```
#create matrix with missing column and row
mat_1 = matrix(rnorm(16), nrow=4, ncol=4, byrow = TRUE) 

#rename columns and rows
dimnames(mat_1) = list(c("a", "c", "d", "e"), c("a", "c", "d", "e")) 

mat_2 <- matrix(
  NA,
  nrow = length(letters[1:5]),
  ncol = length(letters[1:5]),
  dimnames = list(letters[1:5], letters[1:5]))

mat_2[rownames(mat_1), colnames(mat_1)] <- mat_1

mat_2

#            a  b          c           d           e
# a -0.5021924 NA  0.1315312 -0.07891709  0.88678481
# b         NA NA         NA          NA          NA
# c  0.1169713 NA  0.3186301 -0.58179068  0.71453271
# d -0.8252594 NA -0.3598621  0.08988614  0.09627446
# e -0.2016340 NA  0.7398405  0.12337950 -0.02931671
```

Comment: Yeah that was my earlier answer; I had deleted it because it was incomplete and only took care of columns and not of missing rows. +1 for yours. Very nice.

Comment: thanks. what if I have a sequence of letters that do not follow the alphabetical order?

Comment: it doesn't matter, you can just change the dimension names in mat_2.

For example say the missing col/row is called "s" instead of "b" then just use `dimnames = list(c('a', 's', 'c', 'd', 'e'), c('a', 's', 'c', 'd', 'e'))` in mat_2 and the rest stays the same

Comment: and by the way the "missing" col and row names don't even have to be the same name, you can try `dimnames = list(c('a', 's', 'c', 'd', 'e'), c('a', 'f', 'c', 'd', 'e'))`